# Ajax upload using jQuery has errors. File is uploaded properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm working on image upload using jQuery Ajax and Golang. I'm using FormData on javascript and FormFile on the Golang side.

The file gets uploaded properly on the server side, but the client side jQuery gives errors.

My js code -

```
                          canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                            var formData = new FormData();
                            
                            formData.append('avatar', blob, 'avatar.jpg');
                            $.ajax({
                              method: 'POST',
                              type: 'POST',
                              data: formData,
                              processData: false,
                              contentType: false,
                              xhr: function () {
                                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                
                                xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                                  var percent = '0';
                                  var percentage = '0%';
                
                                  if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                    percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                                    percentage = percent + '%';
                                    $progressBar.width(percentage).attr('aria-valuenow', percent).text(percentage);
                                  }
                                };
                
                                return xhr;
                              },
                              url: 'http://localhost:9002/upload/',
                              success: function () {
                                $alert.show().addClass('alert-success').text('Upload success');
                              },
                              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                avatar.src = initialAvatarURL;
                                $alert.show().addClass('alert-warning').text('Upload error - Coudn\'t upload');
                                alert("Json Error (jqHHR) - " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                                alert("Json Error (jqHHR status ) - " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR.status));
                                alert("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                              },
                              complete: function () {
                                $progress.hide();
                              },
                            });
                          });
```

The server code in Golang -

```
func UploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("In Upload Function")
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }
    err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err.Error())
        log.Printf("The error is - %v", err.Error())
        return
    }

    file, handle, err := r.FormFile("avatar")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err.Error())
        log.Printf("The error is - %v", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    mimeType := handle.Header.Get("Content-Type")
    switch mimeType {
    case "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png":
        saveFile(w, file, handle)
    default:
        jsonResponse(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid file")
    }
    log.Println("Uploaded properly")
}

func saveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, file multipart.File, handle *multipart.FileHeader) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        //fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = ioutil.WriteFile("./files/"+handle.Filename, data, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err.Error())
        return
    }
    jsonResponse(w, http.StatusCreated, "File Upload successfully")
}

func jsonResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, message string) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    //fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", message)
}
```

The response from javascript -

```
(jqXHR) - {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":201,"statusText":"Created"}
(jqHHR status ) - 201
parsererror : SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF
```

The file is uploaded properly. But How can I remove these errors? readyState is 4, meaning operation is complete.

Comment: I've added the entire project in a public Gihub repo - https://github.com/nitin-gyany/cropper-upload-golang.git

Comment: It's definitely a template issue. The templates in Golang are questionable development and looks half baked.
Like, if there is something wrong in the template, the REST request is run once again.
The code works fine in a generalised way, without templates. But when the same code is inserted in a templated html file, it gives error on client side.